# BGP NLRI / how much prefixes can be sent

Tags: routes, bgp

the question is about BGP update messages, namely about the maximal amount of prefixes which can be places in an NLRI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No limit, other than the limit on the maximum size BGP Message.  You can, in principle, mix withdrawn and reachable NLRI, and withdrawn/reachable NLRI for different AFI/SAFI... but I would not recommend it.

Comment: could I see somewhere an example of an NLRI with several prefixes, from example a sample from the BGPStream, thanks

Comment: The [RIPE RIS](https://www.ripe.net/analyse/internet-measurements/routing-information-service-ris) has a huge collection of real BGP Messages.  See, in particular, the [Raw Data](https://www.ripe.net/analyse/internet-measurements/routing-information-service-ris/ris-raw-data).

Comment: I used pybgpstream library and extracted a range of messages but have not seen a message with several prefixes. That is the reason for my question.

Comment: btw the BGP message descriptions are not intuitive for me, I have not found a good explanation yet.

Comment: Where there are multiple prefixes they all have the same Attributes.  The routes advertised by a peer will (generally) have the same attributes (they are all routes to prefixes within the peer's AS).  So, when a BGP session comes up, the peer's messages may contain multiple prefixes.  So looking for messages from a given neighbor just after a BGP OPEN may help.  Or just after a Route Refresh.  The sender does not have to collect together prefixes in this way.  What a sender does depends on the internal mechanics for generating updates and the timing of changes which require those updates.

Comment: I just looked at libBGPStream.  I have a strong feeling that each call of `get_next_record(record)` is reading the next BGP message.  Then each `record.get_next_elem()`  is returning one element, containing one prefix, iterating through all the prefixes in the BGP message.